# Maven Unable to parse configuration of mojo for parameter #

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Did a maven build using a custom maven plugin. Got the following error:

```
Unable to parse configuration of mojo <mojo name> for parameter #: Cannot find default setter in class <custom mojo class>
```

What does "#" mean?

Normally if the plugin complains about a configuration parameter, it prints the actual parameter that it doesn't recognize. The pom.xml configuration section for the mojo looks normal.